# Ant Successful even when Ant Task fails

Tags: ant

There must be a simple setting I am missing so forgive me, but I've noticed on two occasions that my bad ant tasks do not cause the build to fail. For example:

1. Ant copy when source file does not exist ... BUILD SUCCESSFUL
2. Ant unzip, when task reports "can't write file" or similar message ... BUILD SUCCESSFUL
3. Ant exec error, invalid syntax ... BUILD SUCCESSFUL

**How do I guarantee all ant task errors will result in a build failure?**

Comment: Many tasks have parameters to switch on/off "failonerror" because sometimes you don't want the task to fail the build. Check the documents and look at the param table carefully.

Comment: @coolcfan, It should always fail unless directed otherwise, EXEC defaulting to false is a bug. I think the COPY and UNZIP issues I have are related to trying to run the ant-launcher.jar directly. :(

Comment: I added failonerror="true" and Ant is still continuing the build. Where is "fail early fail often" in this program?

Answer (score 9):

- `<EXEC>` tasks do no fail by default. You need to enable this with `failonerror="true"`
- Failure of the Ant `<COPY>` task depends on what resource collection type is used. If you use a `fileset` or `patternset`, then all missing files are **silently ignored**. You can force a failure only by using the `filelist` type or the parameterized 'file` attribute is used.

  Therefore what you want to use is either:

  ```
  <copy todir="my_dir" file="foo" />

  <copy todir="my_dir" flatten="true">
    <filelist dir="" files="foo" />
  </copy>

  <copy todir="my_dir" flatten="true">
    <filelist dir="">
       <file name="foo" />
       <file name="bar" />
       <file name="zed" />
    </filelist>
  </copy>
  ```

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried following:

```
<copy todir="your/path/details" failonerror="true">
</copy>

<zip destfile="your/path/details" whenempty="fail">
</zip>

<exec executable="your/path/details" failonerror="true">
</exec>
```

Comment: copy defaults to failonerror="true" and even manually setting it does not produce a failure.

Comment: copy task doesnt work as failureOnError is set to true by default anyway.